# Is it possible to Overload Constructor's in PHP

Tags: php, methods

e.g in C# you can overload methods using the same method name but what about PHP?

```
 class Database {
    private $dsn;
    private $host;
    private $user;
    private $password;
    private $enckey;

    function __construct($dbname, $host, $user, $password) {
        $this->dsn = "mysql:dbname=" . $dbname . ';host=' . $host;
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->password = $password;
}
    function __construct($dbname, $host, $user, $password, $enckey) {
        $this->dsn = "mysql:dbname=" . $dbname . ';host=' . $host;
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->password = $password;
        $this->enckey = $enckey;
    }
}
```

Comment: No. PHP does not support overloading in that way at all due to its dynamic nature

Comment: Why overload when you can specify default values? And PHP is dynamically typed...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What's the point?

```
class Database {
    private $dsn;
    private $host;
    private $user;
    private $password;
    private $enckey;

    function __construct($dbname, $host, $user, $password, $enckey = null) {
        $this->dsn = "mysql:dbname=" . $dbname . ';host=' . $host;
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->password = $password;
        $this->enckey = $enckey;
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens exactly when you make the parameter enckey = null?

Comment: It becomes an optional parameter with the default value being `null`